# mange time format between angularjs - php - mysql

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have trouble to manage time format between angularjs(javascript) - php - mysql . I stored time like 24:00:00, 12:00:00,01:30:00,05:34:00 from angular to mysql via php. Here i m using mysql's time type. While receiving the time via php from mysql's i got as string , but javascript ill understand date object then only i can able to show as time to views . Is any idea to handle this situation?  I am used some time picker but those are not make my result better , I added the list of used plugins , please refer and also you my guide me to handle this .

[Demo link](http://www.dnasir.com/github/angular-timepicker/demo.html)

[github link](https://github.com/Geta/angular-timepicker)

here this author used as directive but i ill initialize model with above mentioned time format , i get invalidate date as result in console while pick the date , after  submission the nulled value only passed as model value to server.

Comment: All of those widgets seem broken, try using them with keyboard only (select using tab, cursor keys to select value). Tabbing across the inputs leaves all the drop downs open.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is easier to work with `Date.prototype.getTime()`

```
var birthday = new Date(1994, 12, 10);
var time = birthday.getTime(); // 789696000000
var date2 = new Date(time); // Same as birthday
```

Then in the back end you can transform it into date with a simple helper. I have some C# (Migrate it to PHP or should be easy) code that do the job:

```
public class JsDateHelper : IJsDateHelper
{
    public DateTime FromUnixTime(double unixTime)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTime);
    }

    public long ToUnixTime(DateTime date)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return Convert.ToInt64((date - epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

By doing it this way you will store in database the number `789696000000` and pass it to angular in angular you will transform it into an actual date using `new Date(789696000000)` I think this way reduces complexity because you only have to worry about the format when you are going display the date.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @SureshVelusamy did you resolve your problem? can you please close the question if so? thanks